# Oracle SQL max() with group by - duplicated values

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a simplified version of a query I created that gives me what I want (a list of all stud_id with the selected cpnt_id, whether there is a value in compl_dte or not, but only if the UserInput for Item is limited to only 1 record.

```
select stud.*, lrnhist.* from
(select s.stud_id,
        i.cpnt_id
from student s, item i
where s.stud_id in [UserInput]
      c.cpnt_id in [UserInput]
) stud
left outer join
(select lh.stud_id,
        lh.cpnt_id,
        max(lh.compl_dte) compl_dte
from learnhist lh
where lh.cpnt_id in [UserInput]
group by lh.stud_id, lh.cpnt_id
) 
on stud.stud_id = lrnhist.stud_id
```

When it is run where UserInput specifies 2 or more Items, it returns the correct rows, but the returned value of compl_dte is always identical for each value of stud_id (because of the use of max(compl_dte) I'm sure).  I'm just not sure what I need to do to make sure the returned compl_dte is the max for the stud_id/cpnt_id pair, not the max for stud_id regardless of cpnt_id.

Table values:

```
student
stud_id
1
2
3
4
item
cpnt_id
a
b
c
d
learnhist
stud_id cpnt_id compl_dte
1    a    5/5/2017
1    a    3/3/2016
1    b    10/10/2016
2    c    8/8/2016
3    b    2/2/2017
```

Results where UserInput is stud_id = * and cpnt_id = a:

```
stud_id cpnt_id compl_dte
1    a    5/5/2017
2    a
3    a
4    a
```

which is correct.
Results where UserInput is stud_id = * and cpnt_id = both a and b:

```
stud_id cpnt_id compl_dte
1    a    5/5/2017
1    b    5/5/2017
2    a
2    b
3    a    2/2/2017
3    b    2/2/2017
4    a
4    b
```

which is not what I'm looking for.  Results I'm looking for in that case:

```
stud_id cpnt_id compl_dte
1    a    5/5/2017
1    b    10/10/2016
2    a
2    b
3    a
3    b    2/2/2017
4    a
4    b
```

First post here, hopefully that all makes sense and I've asked in the right place!

Comment: it would be better to have sql fiddle to to help u test what we have in mind if the query require many joins. Try to use cross join in item and left join with key student id and cpnt id both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem may be a missing join predicate between the `STUD` and `LRNHIST` inline views.
In the query you provided, the `STUD` inline view is a cartesian product between `STUDENT` and `ITEM`, which is then outer joined to the `LRNHIST` view that indeed has one `CMPL_DTE` per `STUD_ID`/`CPNT_ID` pair.  But since the `OUTER JOIN` only predicates on `STUD_ID`, you'll also get matches where `STUD.CPNT_ID <> LRNHST.CPNT_ID`, providing extra rows.

You break it down and look at the inline views individually:

For the `STUD` query:

```
SELECT STUDENT.STUD_ID, ITEM.CPNT_ID FROM STUDENT 
CROSS JOIN ITEM
WHERE STUDENT.STUD_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
AND ITEM.CPNT_ID IN ('a','b','c','d');
```

Result:

```
stud_id     cpnt_id
1   a
1   b
1   c
1   d
2   a
2   b
2   c
2   d
... etc
```

So we can expect all these rows in the final query.

If you look at `LRNHST` individually:

```
SELECT LEARNHIST.STUD_ID,
                LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID,
                 MAX(LEARNHIST.COMPL_DTE) COMPL_DTE
                 FROM LEARNHIST
                 GROUP BY LEARNHIST.STUD_ID, LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID;
```

There is indeed only one row per stud_id-cpnt_id pair (that exists in `learnhist`):

```
stud_id     cpnt_id     compl_dte
1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
3   b   February, 02 2017 00:00:00
2   c   August, 08 2016 00:00:00
```

Now if you join using only `STUD_ID`, you'll get a `May 5th` row for where `STUD` has `1 - a` and `LRNHST` has `1 - a`, but you'll also get a row where `LRNHST` has `1 -b`, because there is no join predicate on `CPNT_ID`. If you select ALL five columns, you can see where the duplication comes in:

```
SELECT STUD.*, LRNHIST.* FROM (
SELECT STUDENT.STUD_ID, ITEM.CPNT_ID FROM STUDENT 
CROSS JOIN ITEM
WHERE STUDENT.STUD_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
AND ITEM.CPNT_ID IN ('a','b','c','d')) STUD
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT LEARNHIST.STUD_ID,
                LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID,
                 MAX(LEARNHIST.COMPL_DTE) COMPL_DTE
                 FROM LEARNHIST
                 GROUP BY LEARNHIST.STUD_ID, LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID
                ) LRNHIST
ON STUD.STUD_ID = LRNHIST.STUD_ID
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC, 3 ASC, 4 ASC, 5 ASC;
```

Result:

```
s_stud  s_cpnt  l_stud  l_cpnt  l_compl

1   a   1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
1   a   1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
1   b   1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
1   b   1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
1   c   1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
1   c   1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
1   d   1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
1   d   1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
2   a   2   c   August, 08 2016 00:00:00
... etc
```

Because this only joins on `stud_id`, both the `Oct` and `May` records are free to match `STUD`'s `1-a` matches `LRNHST`'s `1` for in both its `1-a` groud and `1-b` group.

Now if you join with `CPNT_ID` as well, only the `LRNHST` records that match *Both* `CPNT_ID` and `STUD_ID` will be returned. (`May` for `1-a` and `Oct` for `1-b`)

```
SELECT STUD.STUD_ID, STUD.CPNT_ID, LRNHIST.COMPL_DTE FROM (
SELECT STUDENT.STUD_ID, ITEM.CPNT_ID FROM STUDENT 
CROSS JOIN ITEM
WHERE STUDENT.STUD_ID IN (1,2,3,4)
AND ITEM.CPNT_ID IN ('a','b','c','d')) STUD
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT LEARNHIST.STUD_ID,
                LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID,
                 MAX(LEARNHIST.COMPL_DTE) COMPL_DTE
                 FROM LEARNHIST
                 GROUP BY LEARNHIST.STUD_ID, LEARNHIST.CPNT_ID
                ) LRNHIST
ON STUD.STUD_ID = LRNHIST.STUD_ID
AND STUD.CPNT_ID = LRNHIST.CPNT_ID
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

Result:

```
stud_id     cpnt_id     compl_dte
1   a   May, 05 2017 00:00:00
1   b   October, 10 2016 00:00:00
1   c   (null)
1   d   (null)
2   a   (null)
2   b   (null)
2   c   August, 08 2016 00:00:00
2   d   (null)
... etc
```

Now you should have only one row per `STUD_ID` `CPNT_ID` pair, with nulls for `compl_dte` where no `LRNHST` record matches.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for all the detail!  That did the trick and it looks like it's coming out as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use a factored subquery.

```
WITH all_ids AS (
SELECT s.stud_id as stud_id,
       i.cpnt_id as cpnt_id
  FROM student s
CROSS JOIN item i )
SELECT stud_id, cpnt_id, max(lh.compl_dte) as compl_dte
  FROM all_ids
LEFT JOIN learnhist lh USING (stud_id, cpnt_id)
 WHERE cpnt_id IN ('a', 'b')
GROUP BY stud_id, cpnt_id
ORDER BY stud_id;
```